# What is the store that sells the famous alpaca socks for Bitcoin?

Tags: history, merchants

In the [now-sort-of-viral Bitcoin video](http://www.weusecoins.com/), one notable mention of Bitcoin use was to buy alpaca socks. What is the store that sells or used to sell those iconic socks for Bitcoin?

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Google search gets updated and varies between people. Bitcoin business come, go and get replaced.

Comment: Then the question should be closed as too localised probably.

Comment: This is one of the first Bitcoin merchants - a part of Bitcoin history in my opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be Grass Hill Alpacas at http://www.grasshillalpacas.com/

From their website:

> Grass Hill Alpacas is located on 115 acres that has been in the family for over 125 years. The farm is located at the foot of Grass Hill in the Haydenville section of the town of Williamsburg, just 10 minutes from the center of Northampton. The last time the land was actively farmed was in the 70's, when the last of Stanley "Stubby" Nash’s oxen were sold. Currently our operations are based on 5 acres of old pasture land that we have reclaimed and fenced in. With more than 40 acres of fields, we have plenty of room for expansion as needed.
>
> We brought our first 6 alpacas onto the farm in the summer of 2006. It has been an exciting, rewarding time for our family and our farm. We have learned alot, had some great experiences and built wonderful new friendships that will last a lifetime. But the best part of it all is that we did it together as a family...side-by-side... working the same land that great-great-grampie worked.

Also, don't forget this song about the famous alpaca socks:

[Max Min - Alpaca Socks (Official Music Video)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYqqS7aTBVQ)